# Как в одном сообщении от телеграм бота отправить и текст, и фото?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Telegram, python, pyTelegramBotAPI.
Как к тексту прикрепить фотографию?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

У метода send_photo есть параметр caption в него можно положить текст.

bot.send_photo(id, photo, caption='желаемый текст')