# Как вставить фотку в bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, )

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot

Столкнулся с такой проблемой: Надо вставить фотографию в код, не `bot.send_photo`, а в `bot.send_message`.

Возможно ли это как то сделать?

**Пример Кода**:

```
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def welcome(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "Хай")
 
    # keyboard
    keyboard = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
    Key_1 = types.KeyboardButton("1")
    Key_2 = types.KeyboardButton("2")
    keyboard.add(Key_1, Key_2)
    bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text="Выбери, то что тебе нужно: " ,reply_markup=keyboard)
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text", "sticker", "pinned_message", "photo", "audio"])
def get_text_messages(message):
    if message.text == "1":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Давай посмотрим: ")
        keyboard1 = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
        key_url = types.InlineKeyboardButton(text='Узнать больше', url='https://yandex.ru', callback_data='url')
        keyboard1.add(key_url)
        text1=(first)
        photo1 = open('1.png', 'rb')
        #Вот сюда мне надо вставить фотографию               ||||тут||||
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, text=text1, photo=photo1,reply_markup=keyboard1)
    elif message.text == "/help":
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Напиши /start")
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Я тебя не понимаю. Напиши /help.")
```

Comment: Хотелось бы сделать как то так:
https://wmpics.pics/pm-VAF50.html

Comment: Одним сообщением, не отдельно картинка и текст, а всё вместе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не знаю как решить эту проблему, однако для ускорения процесса решения проблемы стоит указать какую библиотеку вы используете. (Я не могу написать это в комментариях потому что у меня мало репутации).
Однако, если вы используете telebot (или PyTelegranBotAPI), то вам может помочь это решение:

```
bot.send_photo(id, photo, caption='Вставьте текст')
```

Ссылаясь на данный ответ:
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/996136/395518

Comment: извините, да использую telebot, просто уже заманался с этим кодом. Забыл указать, хотя по тегам можно было увидеть Telegrambotapi

Comment: Щас попробовал, спасибо большое, помогло. 2 дня искал ответ. Документация фигня у telegrambotapi. Либо я недосмотрел)

Comment: всегда есть примеры и `Ctrl+F` - https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/09041b018f36cf4c3acc90a641e8ea187cd43d19/examples/detailed_example/detailed_example.py#L109

Comment: Не замечал, теперь буду знать Violet!

Answer (score 1):

Для этого в telebot есть `bot.send_photo(id, photo, caption='желаемый текст')`
Если ответ помог, поставь галочку слева